# Angular 10 erroring in IE11

Tags: angular

I've upgraded to Angular 10 today, all works fine except it no longer works in IE11.

The errors aren't that helpful.

[image]

Only suggestions I've seen online are that it is something to deal with in the polyfills.ts file. Initially I had the following before the upgrade:

```
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
```

However that was then erroring after the upgrade so I had to uncomment it. However either way IE11 still doesn't work. Has anyone else encountered problems with Angular 10 and IE11?

EDIT: I've just tried creating a brand new project and that doesn't work in IE11 either so this looks like a big oversight from the Angular team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular team seems to have fixed this now in new Angular 11.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s how you can work in IE11 when developing:
Add a new `tsconfig-es5.app.json` file.
Update `angular.json` configuration.
Run your application: `ng serve --configuration es5`. I recommend to add a run script in `package.json` for convenience.

In `tsconfig-es5.app.json`

```
{
 "extends": "./tsconfig.app.json",
 "compilerOptions": {
     "target": "es5" 
  }
}
```

In `angular.json`

```
"build": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
  "options": {
      ...
  },
  "configurations": {
    "production": {
        ...
    },
    "es5": {
      "tsConfig": "./tsconfig-es5.app.json"
    }
  }
},
"serve": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
  "options": {
      ...
  },
  "configurations": {
    "production": {
     ...
    },
    "es5": {
      "browserTarget": "yourAppName:build:es5"
    }
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this line in your polyfill.ts file to fix missing imports:

```
import 'core-js/es7/array'
```

And in order to fix Invalid calling object:

```
import 'core-js/es7/object'
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I just tried those but it won't build. Says it can't find those modules. Do I need to npm install anything?

Comment: Install this https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-js @AndrewJuniorHoward

Comment: Thanks just installed it via "npm i core-js" but it still says it can't find the 2 modules you've mentioned